# If both $f$ and $-f$ are convex functions, then $f$ is affine

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Prove that if both $f$ and $-f$ are convex functions, then $f$ is affine

#### My attempt

If $f$ is convex, $f(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)x) \le \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x)$

If $-f$ is convex, $-f(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)x) \le -(\lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x))$
which can be written as $f(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)x) \ge \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x)$

So since $$ \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x)\le f(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)x) \le \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x)$$
it follows that $$f(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)x) = \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x)$$ Thus, $f$ it is an affine function with C = 0.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: It is correct. I have no idea what you mean by $C=0$. The (a) definition of an affine function is $f(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)x) = \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by $C=0$. Apart from that the only error is the meaningless equals sign at the beginning of the displayed line; presumably you mean something like $\iff$.

Comment: Looks good to me, except for your final conclusion. Why do you think that $C=0$? (And what do you mean by that, anyway? I'm _assuming_ that you mean $C = f(0)$, but you haven't actually said so.) (Edit: Oh, hey, didn't see the other comments before...)

Comment: I think that an affine function is of the form $f(x)=\langle a,x \rangle +C$ for some  $a\in X$ and a constant $C\in \mathbb R.$ I think here $C=0$ means this constant $C=0$. In other words, $C=f (0)$

Answer (score 1):

> Thus, f   is an affine function with C = 0.

As commenters remarked, "$C=0$" is neither explained, nor   correct. The proof up to 
$$f(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)x) = \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x)\tag1$$
is fine, but how to conclude that $f$ is of the form $f(x) = b\cdot x+c$?

One way to do this:

1. Since (1) is preserved under adding a constant, subtract $f(0)$ from $f$. Now $f(0)=0$.
2. Using (1) with $x=0$ we get $f(\lambda y) = \lambda f(y)$. This is true for $0<\lambda\le 1$, hence (by considering the reciprocal) also for $\lambda>1$.
3. Let $b$ be the vector formed by $f(e_i)$, where $e_i$ form the standard basis. Observe that $f(x)-b\cdot x$ satisfies (1), and vanishes at all $e_i$.
4. $f(x)-b\cdot x$ vanishes on the convex hull of $\{e_i\}$, hence (by 2) on the entire space.